# TeXlicpse TODO-Comment doesn't show in Task-List

Tags: eclipse, latex, eclipse-plugin

I am using the TeXlipse-Plugin for the first time.

There is a Todo/Task-Support as you can see in the [Manual](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/markers.html).

But if i do a comment like '%TODO: Do something' in my file, the task is not shown in the task-view of Eclipse.

Do i have to activate the todo-support somewhere?

Comment: ok, thanks to all of you. Don´t know why, but after going to General/Editors/Structured Text Editors/Task tags and clicked apply, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me with `% TODO test`. I would check for the following things in your case:

- Check whether the corresponding annotation is displayed to the left (next to the line number) - it looks like the icon of the task view. If not (and be sure, that there is no other annotation - e.g. a warning - because it can hide the task annotation), then the annotation is not created, and then I would follow Robs answer to define your own todo tag in Preferences on the General/Editors/Structured Text Editors/Task tags
- Check the settings of the Tasks view - open the view menu (small triangle at the upper right corner), and choose configure contents. There try to validate the displayed task tags. I attach a screenshot that sets the TODO tags to be displayed only on the current project.

[image: My content settings that display the task tags only from the current project]
<sub>(source: [cubussapiens.hu](http://cubussapiens.hu/taskview-config.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The manual at the link states "In the Eclipse Java Editor, it is possible to place TODO, FIXME and XXX keywords in comments, [...]", so it's not actually promised by TeXlipse.

Anyways, I'd try % //TODO .., maybe it's just supported that way.

If that won't work for you, try defining your own todo-tag under "window" -> "preferences" -> search: "todo"

hth